Jmeter - how to log "response body" in the log file
I've an issue with my project. I'm trying to log the response body and cheking it in the generated report. But I can't see the corresponding column:
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
I tryed to do this:

JSR223 PostProcessor whit this:

def responseBody = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
vars.put("responseBody", responseBody);


BeanShell Sampler with this:

import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;

SampleResult.setResponseData(vars.get("responseBody").getBytes());

IMPORTANT: I'm executing the project in CLI mode
But it didn't work
Anybody can help me? I will be grateful
Thanks...
Expected results:
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage, responseBody,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect

In order to add an extra column to the .jtl results file containing a JMeter Variable value you need to declare the relevant Sample Variable
Either run JMeter providing the Sample Variable name via -J command line argument:
jmeter -Jsample_variables=responseBody -n -t test.jmx -f -l result.jtl

or in order to make the change permanent add the next line to user.properties file:
sample_variables=responseBody

More information:

Configuring JMeter
Overriding Properties Via The Command Line
Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide


Nice !
It does work
Thanks a lot Ivan
